# how to assign values for a vector<Point3f> datatype

Tags: opencv, vector

OK guys, i have the x ,y and z coordinates for a set of points of an image and I want to transfer it to a `vector<Point3f>`. I do not know how to use `vector.push_back()` to pushback individual elements, so is there some other way as simple as the `push_back` for me to use ?

Comment: Why can't you use `vector.push_back()`?

Comment: yeah! sorry I had no idea I could use push_back like Kiell said , so ,yes you can use pushback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
    vector<Point3f> points;
    points.push_back(Point3f(0.44,0.30,0.46));
                                x    y    z
```

Comment: But it uses push_back, and you said that wasn't an option

Comment: @B... he didn't say it wasn't an option, he said "I can't" :D

Comment: I assumed there was some technical reason for that, because the actual question was "is there some other way".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to fill a vector without using `pushback(), with C++11

```
void push_points(int N, float* x float* y, float* z, std::vector<cv::Point3f>& points)
{
    points.resize(N);
    for(cv::Point3f & point : points)
        point = cv::Point3f(x, y, z);
}
```

And with old C++

```
void push_points(int N, float* x float* y, float* z, std::vector<cv::Point3f>& points)
{
    points.resize(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        points[i] = cv::Point3f(x, y, z);
}
```